# MailKit can't connect to Google SMTP server

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit, .net-7.0

I am using MailKit in my project to send email. When I try to connect to smtp.gmail.com an exception is thrown in client.ConnectAsync() method. My EmailSender class code is below:

```
using MimeKit;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

public class EmailSender
{ 
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
        var addressFrom = new MailboxAddress("username",
                                             "email");
        var addressTo = new MailboxAddress(string.Empty,
                                           email);

        emailMessage.From.Add(addressFrom);
        emailMessage.To.Add(addressTo);
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
        {
            Text = message,
        };

        using var client = new SmtpClient();

        await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com",
                                  465,
                                  useSsl: true);



        client.Authenticate(addressFrom.Address,
                            "password");
        await client.SendAsync(emailMessage);
        await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.'
```

I tried to ping gmail smtp server from command line, and all is okey with reaching this server. Also tried to connect via TSL on 587 port, but had the same problem.

Comment: I remeber that you need to activate "allow less secure apps" in google settings, but the snack bar states that it is no longer possible. Just try to activate that option and tell me if it worked https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: @Hille i am using Google account with 2FA and generated app password. As far as I understand the problem occurs at the stage of connect to SMTP server `client.ConnectAsync()`, where we didn't specified any account data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many things, but the problem was not on my side. It looks like my ISP is blocking this connection. When I used my mobile phone as a modem, everything worked correctly.